# .NET Regex Split String into Word Pairs

Tags: .net, regex

I have a string "word1 word2 word3 word4 word5"

I would like to Split that into an array of:
"word1 word2" | "word2 word3" | "word3 word4" | "word4 word5"

I can do it using a .NET split and loop, but I'd rather do it with a regex using Regex.Split

Here's the working split and loop:

```
Dim keywordPairArr As String() = Regex.Split(Trim(keywords), "[ ]")
For i As Integer = 0 To keywordPairArr.Length - 2
    Dim keyword As String = keywordPairArr(i) & " " & keywordPairArr(i + 1)
    If Not keywordDictionary.ContainsKey(keyword) Then
        keywordDictionary.Add(keyword, Regex.Matches(keywords, "[" & keyword & "]+").Count)
    End If
Next
```

Bonus:  Every N-th word would be nice.  N=3 would output "word1 word2 word3" | "word2 word3 word4" | "word3 word4 word5"

Any help on the Regex for spliting the string by every Nth [ ]?

Comment: Good. Come back with regex solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Regex.Matches()` for this task.

Here's a C# example that will output the result:

```
void PrintWordGroups( string input, string pattern )
{
    MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches( input.Trim(), pattern );
    foreach ( Match m in mc )
    {
        Trace.WriteLine( m.ToString() );
    }
}

void PrintGroupsOf2( string input )
{
    PrintWordGroups( input, @"([^\s]+\s+[^\s]+)\s*" );
}

void PrintGroupsOf3( string input )
{
    PrintWordGroups( input, @"(([^\s]+\s+){2}[^\s]+)\s*" );
}

void PrintGroupsOfN( string input, int n )
{
    string pattern = string.Format( @"(([^\s]+\s+){{{0}}}[^\s]+)\s*", n - 1 );
    PrintWordGroups( input, pattern );
}
```

**Assumptions:**

- The words are delimited by whitespace.
- The number of words in the input must be multiply of the number of words in a group (e.g. 3, 6, 9, 12, etc. for groups of 3 words).

**Patterns Explained:**

1. `([^\s]+\s+[^\s]+)\s*` - capture word->whitespace->word->optional whitespace (optional because the last expression won't have it due to the `Trim()` operation in `PrintWordGroups()`).
2. `([^\s]+\s+){2}` means: capture word->whitespace twice then finish with another word and then the optional whitespace.
3. `string.Format( @"(([^\s]+\s+){{{0}}}[^\s]+)\s*", n - 1 )`
   This is the generic case for capturing N-1 words + whitespaces and then finishing with the Nth word and the optional whitespace.

   For example, if n=6, the formatted string will be: `(([^\s]+\s+){5}[^\s]+)\s*`.